# how do I return a Bearer Token supplied by my server

Tags: swift, authorization, bearer-token, vapor

I'm using Vapor to handle http requests. I've implemented a registration and login, as well as other functioning code. On registration, a Bearer Token is generated, so I can return that to or write it into the page I'm about to render.

The page contains two forms, one of which generates a request that requires authorization, so I need to associate that request with the bearer token. How do I do this? Through explicitly setting headers for the form request that will be sent to the server? Via a cookie?

Comment: bearer token is type of auth token you need to pass it in header.

Comment: right, ok, so is this done in the form definition on the server? I've only found descriptions of this done via js in an Ajax context. When I have control of the form received, how do I encode it into the form?

Comment: you don't need to encode. just pass in header like "Bearer Token" : "your token". you get token like this :  for Example `ejfklashik5746sakjkafddsfgsdgfgtfdgfdgfdg`

Comment: Sorry, I appreciate the help, but this isn't clear to me. I know very well that I have to pass a bearer token with some requests, and I can do that via Thunder Client. But if I pass it as part of the response, it won't be specific to a given request, different for each form. So it has to be associated with the form.

Comment: I know I have to return the bearer token as part of the request, I have the bearer token, I don't know how to write the form to ensure that it sends the token

Comment: check here : https://www.raywenderlich.com/9191035-vapor-4-authentication-getting-started it might helps you to understans.

Comment: hey RB's  the more fundamental issue, as Tim points out below, is that you can't use a Bearer Token in a web browser context, something not accounted for in the Vapor Docs. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks to update me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're writing a traditional web app using HTML then bearer authentication is not suitable as you can't attach custom headers with requests. You should use session based authentication as [described in the docs](https://docs.vapor.codes/4.0/authentication/#website-authentication)

Comment: got it. I think the organization of the docs page doesn't make it easy to discern that incompatibility.

Comment: it means it will set from server side. right?

Comment: Kinda, the session ID is passed to the server via a cookie and the user is persisted in the session by Vapor